# How to move up the UIView when the keyboard is appear?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, keyboard, textview, ios-keyboard-extension

i developing a chat application. In my view controller has one tableview. In the bottom the view controller i designed one textview and one button inside customView. When i type into the textview my keyboard will hide the customView(which contains textview and send button). I want to move up the both customView and tableview when i type into the textview.Please anyone help me.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to catch the keyboard notifications and move up/down your textView. You can see how Apple to recommend to do it here: [Apple Documentation: Keyboard Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

in part: Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard